# Any good SEO tracking apps out there?

Tags: seo, rank-checkers

I was wondering if anyone knew of any noteworthy SEO tracking web apps (either free or paid). I.e. i want to be able to track page rankings, rankings against keywords, trends over time etc.

I've seen a couple, but most seem pretty amateur. I was hoping that there might be a gem out there somewhere?

PS. I am aware of the google tools (webmaster and analytics). What I am interested in, is a web solution that will help me pro-actively keep on top of my sites SEO strategy, as well as pro actively alert me to opportunities to increase / enhance exposure.

Comment: Related to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1957/can-anyone-reccommend-a-google-serp-tracker-closed

Comment: Why is this community wiki too? I can't undertand this site, isn't is also about SEO???

Comment: It's community wiki because it's the sort of question where there isn't a single right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a ton of tools out there. Here are a few:

- http://tools.seobook.com/
- http://www.ibusinesspromoter.com/
- http://www.webposition.com/
- http://www.advancedwebranking.com/

There is also http://www.webceo.com/ which was already mentioned.

Comment: It would be good if you split these into separate answers, with a little comment about each, then people who know them can vote for the ones that they like the best.

Answer (score 2):

I would have thought that searching is the best way to find good SEO tools: if the company knows enough about SEO that their products are worth using then they'll be near the top of the lists on relevant searches.

Comment: +1 Completely agree, if they aren't in the top five for your search then they probably aren't very good tools (or at least they aren't very good at using their own tools)

Comment: In theory yes, but what if a new product was launched yesterday? It will take months if not years for it to develop inbound links and ranking to out-compete the current home page...

Comment: I would be wary of trusting my business (assuming the website the SEO is wanted for is intended as a money maker) to a brand new unproven tool, and it doesn't take *that* long to get into decent search positions if you know your SEO - Google and their kin do take site/page age into account but not with that much significance.

Comment: For finding an SEO company to deal with, yes. For finding a software tool to help you do your own SEO, I don't think the creator of that tool will neccesarily have the skills / time to spend on making his tool well ranked, unless they are charging a lot of money for it. I.e. someone who writes good software is not neccesarily someone who gets high SEO rankings.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Web CEO before when it was in version 5.0, currently version 8.1. I would recommend that product, but to be fair have not surveyed the market for competing products.

=> http://www.webceo.com/

Comment: I tested it, it's incredibly slow, too complex, gives useless suggetion. Last, but not least after installation forces you to create an account.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I came across this one a couple of days ago, [pearanalytics](http://www.pearanalytics.com/). It's a little basic for what you want but it does show Google PageRank.

Comment: +1 intersting FREE tool but still buggy. it tell me my site does not validate for CSS which is not true, it says I have no Google site map, which I have, but not in XML.

Answer (score 0):

SEOmoz's [Open Site Explorer](http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/) is a useful link popularity checker & back-link analysis tool.